# How to make a RequireJS App Modular i.e. download files on the go, not at once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, requirejs

I'm working on a huge Web App (AngularJS and RequireJS), in which there are a lot of JS files. (So many Controllers, Filters, Services and so many 3rd party plugins). The problem that I face is, my App takes too much time to download all the files (at once) each time I refresh my App. Can we use any strategy by which we configure our require JS in a way that only the required files should be donwloaded instead of All files?

Currently my Require JS is configured this way:

```
reqire.config({
 paths: {
  angular: '../../',
  jquery: '../../', .......
 }, shim: {
  bootstrap: {
   deps: ['jquery']
 }.........................
});
```

Comment: Just for RequireJS modules, you may want to look at [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy). Mixing it together with Angular is very different, an example is [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at ocLazyLoad for your lazy loading needs- [link](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad)

One strategy is to require the loading of plugins in ui-router's Resolve call. This will load the required dependencies for a view/state before attempting to transition to it, and is promise-aware to ensure that everything loads in the right order.

```
.state('myState', {
          url: '/myState',
          template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in"></div>',
          resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
              function( $ocLazyLoad ){
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(['scripts/controllers/myController.js']);
            }]
          }
        })
```

You can also use it to load multiple files if you so require.

```
.state('ui.map.google', {
            url: '/google',
            templateUrl: 'views/ui/map/google.html',
            controller: 'GoogleMapCtrl',
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                  function( $ocLazyLoad ){
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load( [
                        {
                          files: ['vendor/jquery/load-google-maps.js',
                                  'scripts/controllers/googlemap.js']
                        },
                        {
                          name:'ui.map',
                          files:['vendor/modules/angular-ui-map/ui-map.js']
                        }
                      ]).then(
                      function(){ 
                        return loadGoogleMaps(); 
                      }
                    )
                }]
            }
          })
```

You don't need to do anything special in the controller to make this work, and the ocLazyLoad plugin is very configurable (you can set up manifests/packages, etc).